# Get KeyVault Get Access Policies via Powershell AZ CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to read in the access policies using the az cmdlets but struggling to do this. I thought this would work

```
$foo = az keyvault show -g "my-rg" -n "my-kv"
```

This returns a value back and was hoping to do:

```
$accessPolicies = $foo.accessPolicies
```

However this returns a null. I did notice the output produces `properties` so I also tried

```
$accessPolicies = $foo.properties.accessPolicies
```

Clearly doing something wrong here. Any ideas how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly query the accessPolicies properties from the Azure CLI command.

```
$accessPolicies = az keyvault show -g "my-rg" -n "my-kv" --query 'properties.accessPolicies'
```

The `--query` parameter needs the JMESPath query string. See http://jmespath.org/ for more information and examples.

If you want to use the PowerShell commands, you can do it like this:

```
$accessPolicies= (Get-AzKeyVault -vaultname "my-kv" -resourcegroupname "my-rg").AccessPolicies
```

Comment: I am finding that Get-Az cmdlets are far better as I can access properties directly. But yes this works thanks.